Buffered Image wont draw but will load
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MainCasino extends JPanel{
    Random ra = new Random();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    DrawingPanel pane;
    JFrame window;
    Timer timer;
    
    BufferedImage bg = loadImage("Casinobg.png");
    
    final int PANW = 900;
    final int PANH = 700;
    final int T_SPEED = 15;
    
    int prob;
    int result;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainCasino();
    }
    
    MainCasino(){
        setupGUI();
        monkeyBusiness();
    }
    
    void setupGUI() {
        window = new JFrame("SLOT MACHINE");
        window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PANW, PANH));
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        
        pane = new DrawingPanel();
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PANW, PANH));
        pane.setVisible(true);
        window.add(pane);
        window.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyChar() == ' ') {
                    
                }
            }
        });
    }
    void monkeyBusiness() {
        timer = new Timer(T_SPEED, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                pane.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }
    
    void spin() {
        prob = ra.nextInt(100, 500)+1;
        result = ra.nextInt(prob)+1;
    }
    
    private class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            System.out.println("WOmp");
            g.drawImage(bg, 1, 1, PANW, PANH, null);
        }
    }
    
    static BufferedImage loadImage(String filename) {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An image failed to load: " + filename, "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        return img;
    }
}   

I tried changing the location of the image in the project folder but seems to be in the correct location.
I tried changing the x and y of the image from 0,0 to something lese and that didn't work.
I tried putting a systemout to check if the timer was running (It is)
I do not know what is wrong.

img can be null, you don't check

window.pack, window.setLocationRelativeTo, and window.setVisible need to be the last lines of your setupGUI method.  Do not pack, place, or show a window before its contents have been built.

from the documentation of add(): "This method changes layout-related information, and therefore, invalidates the component hierarchy. If the container has already been displayed, the hierarchy must be validated thereafter in order to display the added component."

and from documentation of pack(): "Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents." - no subcomponent added, no size (or minimal one)

@user85421 The OP (unwisely) sets the frame's preferred size and the DrawingPanels preferred size, so the window will be sized to fit (the frame's preferred size) initially (no child components required).  They are also starting a Timer to repaint the component, so the only foreseeable reason for the image not to be painted is that it's not been loaded (based on my limited testing of the code)

Based on my testing, the only reason I can see that the image isn't been painted is because the image isn't been loaded.  I would check your output for the any error messages.  I'd also be careful about loading images using relative File location, as this assumes the working directory is always the same - I'd make use of embedded resources instead

I'd also encourage the use of Key bindings over KeyListener.  Personally, the image should be associated with the DrawingPanel, either loading itself or dependency injection, directly or via some kind of view model

What is the basis for your belief that the image loaded?

I don't have issues with running your code, once I plug in an image I know will load.  This leads me to believe that the image isn't actually been loaded and either you're not seeing the error message (the JOptionPane maybe displayed behind the frame and the error message maybe getting lost in the noise of other outputs) and you're not handling the possibility of the image been null.  More about this in a second.
However, there are some issues with your workflow which could be improved.
As has already been stated.  Generally, you're better off setting up your UI before you make it visible, it helps with small issues like these.  Also, the window shouldn't be dedicating the size, the main reason for this is because the window decorations are displayed INSIDE the window, making the available space for the viewable content smaller.  Instead, you want to pack the window around the content.  So, in short, don't use setPreferredSize on the window.
So, your setupGUI might look something more like...
void setupGUI() {
    pane = new DrawingPanel();
    pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PANW, PANH));
    
    window = new JFrame("SLOT MACHINE");
    window.add(pane);
    window.pack();
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setVisible(true);
}

This ensures that the viewable area of the window represents the requirements of its content.  It will also, automatically, layout the container hierarchy and paint it for you.
Should you need to dynamically update the UI (ie add/remove/update components) after the window is made visible you MUST call revalidate and repaint yourself.
Your DrawingPanel is also relying on an external state.  You should try and decouple your code, so it supports concepts like encapsulation, and make use of concepts like dependency injection, model view controller and even observer pattern, depending on your needs.   The point been to try and create a stand alone object which is not otherwise directly coupled to other classes/objects.
To that end, I would consider changing the DrawingPanel to be more like...
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage backgroundImage;

    public DrawingPanel(BufferedImage backgroundImage) {
        this.backgroundImage = backgroundImage;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (backgroundImage == null) {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        } else {
            return new Dimension(backgroundImage.getWidth(), backgroundImage.getHeight());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        if (backgroundImage == null) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
            g2d.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2d.drawLine(getWidth(), 0, 0, getHeight());
        } else {
            int x = (getWidth() - backgroundImage.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - backgroundImage.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(backgroundImage, x, y, this);
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}

This makes use of dependency injection to "inject" the object properties.  It decouples the class, making it standalone and encapsulates the functionality, so that, for example, the preferredSize is calculated by the class itself - it's self determinate.

But why doesn't my image paint?

I hear you say.  My guess, as I've already stated, is the fact that you're image isn't actually been loaded and the error handling is failing to provide you with that information.
Taking a closer look...
static BufferedImage loadImage(String filename) {
    BufferedImage img = null;
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An image failed to load: " + filename, "Error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    return img;
}

we can determine that...

The method hides the exception
Can return null, but which you never actually check

I also found the initial JOptionPane was unreliable as the main window was made visible over the top of it ... some what surprising and that could be a user observation issue on my part, but I don't recall seeing it the first time I ran the code.
A better solution would be to allow the exception to propagate back up to the caller.  Essentially, it's not the responsibility of the loadImage method to determine what should be done when it fails, so, instead, I'd do something like...
static BufferedImage loadImage(String filename) throws IOException {
    return ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
}

Now, this is going to cause you issues as you can't handle the exception as part of the variable initialisation workflow, which is why we have things like constructors and dependency injection.
So I'd change your casino class's constructor to be more like...
MainCasino(BufferedImage backgroundImage) { 
    bg = backgroundImage;
    ... 
}

This now forces you to deal with the possible exception before you even try and initiate the MainCasino class.
Another issue is, the use of File and the relative path when loading the image.  The problem is, the "working directory" (or the place the code runs from) isn't always the same place the code is located.  This is a relative common issue with a common solution - embed your resources.
Essentially this just means making sure that the resources you need are available in the class path.  This is typically done by including the resources in the resulting Jar file and making use of Class#getResource at runtime.
How this is done will be based on your IDE and build system, for example, some IDEs/build systems allow you to simply include the resources directly in the source folder, some require them to be placed in "special" directories.  You'll need to research your IDE and build system.
Runnable example...
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                BufferedImage backgroundImage;
                try {
                    backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/apple.png"));
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                    frame.add(new BackgroundPane(backgroundImage));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected class MainPane extends JPanel {

        public MainPane(BufferedImage backgroundImage) {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new BackgroundPane(backgroundImage));
        }

    }

    protected class BackgroundPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage backgroundImage;

        public BackgroundPane(BufferedImage backgroundImage) {
            this.backgroundImage = backgroundImage;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            if (backgroundImage == null) {
                return new Dimension(200, 200);
            } else {
                return new Dimension(backgroundImage.getWidth(), backgroundImage.getHeight());
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (backgroundImage == null) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
                g2d.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                g2d.drawLine(getWidth(), 0, 0, getHeight());
            } else {
                int x = (getWidth() - backgroundImage.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - backgroundImage.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(backgroundImage, x, y, this);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}

